# org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: java, maven, jersey, tomcat7

I was running web service on tomcat server. Unfortunately I receive the following error,

Java 9.0
Tomcat 7.0.47

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/My%20Development_space/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/restService/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.co`enter code here`m/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"
    metadata-complete="false" >
```

Comment: Tomcat 7 is not able to handle JDK module-info. I think you have to to Tomcat 8 or maybe 9...

Comment: Especially not an old Tomcat 7 like that `.47`. At least try the latest version of Tomcat 7 if you want to use Java 9.

Comment: I tried on tomcat 8 also. But issue is not been resolved.

Comment: I am having same issue tomcat 8.0.18 (java8)